# Setting the src of an iFrame with parameters causes X-Frame-Options 'SAMEORIGINS' error

Tags: iframe, reporting-services, asp.net-web-api2, x-frame-options

I'm currently developing a website using `angularjs` for my client side and using `Web API 2` for my server side.

Firstly, I'm attempting to embed an `SSRS` report into my website using an `iframe`. I can successfully embed the report whenever I supply the `iframe` src with the following (example) link:

http://EXAMPLE-LINK/reports/report/Test%20Upgrade/Line%20Control?rs:embed=true

And the image below is the report successfully loaded into the site (happy days):

[image: SSRS report successfully embedded]

Secondly, whenever I use the same link but this time supply it with parameters to populate the "Between" and "And" fields I'm getting the following console error:

[image: Console Error]

The link I'm using that contains the parameters is detailed below:

http://EXAMPLE-LINK/reports/report/Test%20Upgrade/Line%20Control?&date1=01/03/2018&date2=04/04/2018?rs:embed=true"

Finally, how come when I supply the `iframe` src a link with parameters I'm getting the  `X-Frame-Options 'SAMEORIGIN'` error? Ideally I want to supply the `iframe` src with the parameters otherwise I'm going to have to create multiple reports to fulfil the website functionality.

What can I do within my application to ignore / remove the `X-Frame-Options 'SAMEORIGIN'` header response? Do I need to add in some `customHeader` response into my `web.config` or is there a way I can remove the header during the startup of my web app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after trying to access the following link: 
http://EXAMPLE-LINK/reports/report/Test%20Upgrade/Line%20Control?&date1=01/03/2018&date2=04/04/2018?rs:embed=true within my browser URL I was presented with the following error:

[image: Reporting Services Error]

So this lead me to believe that the link I was trying to pass to my `iframe` was in fact incorrect.

So I amended my link to follow the structure below which includes my parameters:

http://EXAMPLE-LINK/reports/report/Test%20Upgrade/Line%20Control?rs:embed=true&date1=01/03/2018&date2=04/04/2018

As you can see I pass the `rs:embed=true` tag before the parameters for the `SSRS` report and success! I'm now able to load in my `iframe` with the `SSRS` report parameters populated.

[image: Working SSRS Report]

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Report Server 2019, you can set a custom `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors <uri>` header.  At least in Chrome, it will respect this value before `X-Frame-Option`.  Additionally, I enable CORS.

This can be done via SSMS.  Connect to the Report Server instance, right click the server and select Properties.  Then go to the Advanced section.  Under "User-defined" you'll find `AccessControlAllowOrigin` (CORS) and `CustomHeaders`.  Here are some example values:

```
AccessControlAllowOrigin: https://prod_app:8888/, http://dev_app:8888/
CustomHeaders: <CustomHeaders><Header><Name>Content-Security-Policy</Name><Pattern>.*</Pattern><Value>frame-ancestors https://prod_app:8888 http://prod_dev:8888</Value></Header></CustomHeaders>
```

This will enable cross-origin requests from `prod_app` running on port 8888 with protocol `https` and allow iframes from all sources (not secure).

I had to reboot the Report Server due to some seemingly server-side caching issues (ReportViewer.aspx didn't apply the custom header for some time).

Finally, if you screw up report server properties and your Report Server fails to load (RSPortal.exe errors, etc.) then you can access the report server properties directly in the SQL database by going to the SQL Database -> ReportServer -> dbo.ConfigurationInfo table and clearing or updating the values.  You will have to restart the Report Server windows service for changes to take affect using this method.